# Hardware compatibility regarding multiple audio interfaces on Intel i5 2G?

Tags: drivers, sound, ati, ubuntu-studio

I am running Windows 7 on my HP Pavilion g6-1225sm (2nd generation Intel Core i5-2450M processor 2.4GHz, Radeon HD6470M graphics, Intel HM65 Express Chipset...). I am also using Focusrite Saffire 6 USB (USB 2.0) audio interface.

I would like to install Ubuntu Studio because I like the Jack Server option for connecting two different audio interfaces to work as one (if I understood it right)... I would like to buy one more audio interface and use it with the one that I already have.

The question:

Is there any version of Ubuntu Studio compatible with this hardware of mine, and where can I download it?

Comment: Given what you've said, every version of Ubuntu Studio would be compatible. However, you have not told us how much RAM you have (which is usually the most important factor in determining which versions and derivatives of Ubuntu will work or work well). How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the compatibility of the hardware is based on the kernel that the OS is running (3.8 in Ubuntu 12.04 and 3.11 in Ubuntu 13.10). I think that you won't have problems to try with Ubuntu Studio 12.04.3 LTS (more stable) and Ubuntu Studio 13.10 (latest) due to the specs of your computer http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=es&lc=es&dlc=es&docname=c03003921#N46

The best thing I think you can do is try with a LiveUSB both version and try with your audio interface and an audio interface that someone could lend you to know with version could work better for you.